# Is there a way to give point to only those who have certain points

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make it so if you die a scoreboard counter will appear and then if a player has a scoreboard counter of 1 then it will detuct some money from a scoreboard account same with if you kill somebody then you will recive some money into your scoreboard account I was thinking it would be something like this /scoreboard players remove @a[something here] Money 250000
or something along those lines, please help me.

Comment: note: this is a lan world

Comment: What have you got in place so far? E.G: What objectives have you got set up? Are you already tracking deaths and kills, or is how to do that part of the question?

Comment: I just want to know if i can target only people who have a score of 1 then to make a different score of 1 and yes i all ready have the death and kill tracker

Comment: sorry about not getting to you sooner i was busy doing other things on the lan world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test for values of scoreboard objectives like this:
Objective <= some number
`/execute @a[score_<objective name>_min=<some number>] <insert commands here...>`
Objective > some number
`/execute @a[score_<objective name>=<some number>] <insert commands here...>`
You don't have to use /execute; any command will work, as long as you follow the target. Hope this helps!